# Labels aren't shown properly in combo box

Tags: apache-flex

The below code show the labels from previously selected list any ideas?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on List AB
2. Open the list but don't select / click any item
3. Now click on List CD
4. Open the list again and you see A, B as labels instead of C,D but if you click on any item then everything comes properly

```
 <mx:Script>
      <![CDATA[
           import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

           public var ab:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([{label: A, data: 1},
                {label: B, data: 2}]);
           public var cd:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([{label: C, data: 3},
                {label: D, data: 4}]);

           private function abClick(event:Event):void
           {
                cb.dataProvider=ab;
           }

           private function cdClick(event:Event):void
           {
                cb.dataProvider=cd;
           }
      ]]>
 </mx:Script>

 <mx:Panel title="ComboBox Control Example"
             height="75%"
             width="75%"
             layout="horizontal"
             paddingTop="10"
             paddingBottom="10"
             paddingLeft="10"
             paddingRight="10">

      <mx:ComboBox id="cb"
                      width="150"/>
      <mx:Button label="List AB"
                   click="abClick(event);"/>
      <mx:Button label="List CD"
                   click="cdClick(event);"/>
 </mx:Panel>
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with this, can you better describe what you expect to see and how this output differs?

Comment: works for me, what version of Flex are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and all I changed was the label value in your array collections `label: A` to `label: "A"` and quoted all the rest (else I got compiler errors).

I compiled your code using flex builder 3 with the 3.2 SDK and could not reproduce the problem. There is nothing I can see wrong with your example code so I have to assume that your issue is more with your compiler or SDK, Which versions are you using?

Comment: There is a bug reported in 3.5 sdk